# How to have each string in an array be its own UITableViewCell, each in its own section?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my `viewDidLoad`, I set up an array of agenda items like so:

```
self.agendaTableArray = @[@"No events today!", @"No events today!", @"No events today!", @"No events today!", @"No events today!", @"No events today!", @"No events today!", @"No events today!", @"No events today!", @"No events today!", @"No events today!", @"No events today!", @"No events today!", @"No events today!", @"No events today!", @"Dinner with Rebekah", @"Soccer game", @"Denist appt.", @"Celebrate job offer, drinks with Pierre!", @"No events today!", @"No events today!", @"No events today!", @"No events today!", @"No events today!", @"No events today!", @"No events today!", @"No events today!", @"No events today!", @"No events today!", @"No events today!"];
```

What I want is for every one of the strings in this array to be in a separate cell, and for every one of those cells to be in its own section. Here's what my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` looks like so far:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyReuseIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = self.agendaTableArray[indexPath.section];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];

    [self whatSectionsAreVisible];

    return cell;
}
```

The problem is that this code throws all of the strings in different cells under the SAME section, rather than in their own section. It also crashes if I try scrolling with the error `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'`

What's incorrect about the way I'm setting up this table that's causing these two issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are returning `1` for the number of rows in each section and the array size for the number of sections from the delegate:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
  return [self.agendaTableArray count];
}
```

Comment: This fixed the crashing, but I'm still seeing only the first string in the array repeated in every section.

Comment: Log `indexPath.section` and `self.agendaTableArray[indexPath.section]` to the console right before setting the label text and see what those values are.

Comment: And make sure you have actual content in your array. The array in your question above is all the same string, so if you use that to test it will be working right but still all be the same string.

Comment: I logged both things and they are logged out correctly, yet the table just shows the same thing repeated. It's not all the same string, if you go to items 16-19 there are different things. I even tried making the 2nd item in the array something different and it doesn't show up. Only the first item in the array shows, and it's repeated 30 times.

Comment: If `indexPath.section` is the correct index for each string in the array and `self.agendaTableArray[indexPath.section]` is logging all of the strings like it should, there's something going on elsewhere that's messing it up. Make sure the labels are all hooked up on the storyboard if you're using a storyboard, and that the delegate and data source for the tableview are set to the class shown above. Perhaps something in your `whatSectionsAreVisible` method?