# UITableView is repeating the same string in every section's cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have an array of strings and want each section in my UITableView to use the respective string as the title of its row. Rather than doing this, it's just taking the first string in the array and repeating it in every section.

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong with the setup. I have the `indexPath.section` and `agendaTableArray` value logging, and it logs correctly as I scroll through the table, but it still only shows the first value.

**Array setup:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

 /// code clipped for brevity

    self.agendaTableArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];

    self.agendaTableArray = @[@"No events today!", @"No events today!", @"Dinner with Rebekah", @"Soccer game", @"Dentist appt.", @"Celebrate job offer, drinks with Pierre!", @"No events today!", @"No events today!", @"No events today!", @"No events today!", @"No events today!", @"No events today!", @"No events today!", @"No events today!", @"No events today!", @"No events today!", @"No events today!"];

}
```

**Table setup:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyReuseIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    }

    NSLog(@"the indexpath.section is: %ld", (long)indexPath.section);
    NSLog(@"the agendaTableArray title is: %@", self.agendaTableArray[indexPath.section]);


    cell.textLabel.text = self.agendaTableArray[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];

    [self whatSectionsAreVisible];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Please, add yours numberofRows and numberOfSection method, it seems like you reversed datasource implementation

Comment: How is this not a repeat of your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31059765/how-to-have-each-string-in-an-array-be-its-own-uitableviewcell-each-in-its-own)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should consider checking how many rows you have per section. In order words, you are probably returning the value 1 for `- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInSection'` , and therefore you are always using the index of your first row, which is 0.

You probably want to use:

```
cell.textLabel.text = self.agendaTableArray[indexPath.section];
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is the following line:

```
cell.textLabel.text = self.agendaTableArray[indexPath.section];
```

It should be:

```
cell.textLabel.text = self.agendaTableArray[indexPath.row];
```

Im making the assumption that you want one row per item on the array and not one section per item on the array.

Comment: Huh? Your suggestion is what the OP is already doing. And that's the problem. Your assumption is incorrect. The question states that the table has one row per section.